# git status doesn't escape paths of untracked files

Tags: git

I noticed that when tracked paths contain spaces or special characters that need escaping, `git status --short` will properly escape them on output. However, for untracked paths, `git status --short` does not escape them, making it very difficult to quickly copy and paste them into a command. What gives? And is it possible to force `git status --short` to escape all paths, including the paths of untracked files?

```
> git --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
git version 2.27.0                                                                                                                                                                             
> git status --short                                                                                                                                                                                                 Mon Sep  7 22:27:36 2020
A  normal_filename
A  "this is also escaped ''"
A  "this is escaped"
?? i'm testing
?? spaced file path
```

Comment: Does it have porcelain output? (It does, as well as -z.)

Comment: I don't have a good answer (other than "looks like a bug" :-) ) but as a workaround, consider writing a little script to use `git status --porcelain=v2 -z` that extracts the untracked file info and prints it in a more useful format for your purpose.

Comment: Figured it might be a bug. I'll go report this issue to the git maintainers if no one on S.O. knows what's going on. Thank you torek

Comment: ... and Brian Carlson already has a proposed patch now :-)

Comment: Yup I filed a bug and he and Junio investigated and came up with a patch the da of basically. I appreciate and love the git maintainers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a bug report. Within one hour, the helpful git maintainers quickly confirmed it was a bug and started patching it. See the bug report [here](https://public-inbox.org/git/3a72c5f2-35cc-a865-d5f2-02706c48d8ec@web.de/T/#t).
I'm expecting it to be fixed in git version > 2.28.

Comment: Looks like this is still an issue with --porcelain=v2 -->
`git status --short`:  `A  "file with space.txt"`
`git status --porcelain` : `A  "file with space.txt"`
`git status --porcelain=v2`: ....... `file with space.txt` <== unquoted

Answer (score 2):

Git does quote some paths, but not others.  The criteria are specified in the `core.quotePath` configuration:

> Commands that output paths (e.g.  ls-files, diff), will quote "unusual" characters in the pathname by enclosing the pathname in double-quotes and escaping those characters with backslashes in the same way C escapes control characters (e.g.  \t for TAB, \n for LF, \ for backslash) or bytes with values larger than 0x80 (e.g. octal \302\265 for "micro" in UTF-8).…Double-quotes, backslash and control characters are always escaped regardless of the setting of this variable. A simple space character is not considered "unusual".

So the intention is not to quote things to help you at the command line, but rather to provide the output in an unambiguous way.  I've checked with the latest version of Git (and in the source code) and the same function is called for both tracked and untracked files, so the behavior is consistent, if not what you were looking for.

If you're looking for something to script, you definitely want `git status --porcelain -z` (or `--porcelain=v2`), which will provide a consistent format with NUL termination.

Comment: Thanks @bk2204. I was using 2.27 which is fairly recent. I'll test it on 2.28. I don't want to use porcelain mode because I want to preserve colors but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Same thing is happening in 2.28. Thanks for investigating that the same function is called.

Comment: There really isn't a way to get what you want without some sort of scripting.  Git doesn't provide a way to quote all paths like you're looking for.